# How do I get the position of a UniversalCamera in babylon.js?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I'm trying to log the Vector3 position of a BABYLON UniversalCamera in the console.

I've tried using `camera.getTarget()`, but it isn't returning the camera's current position.

Here's my code.

```
let camera = new BABYLON.UniversalCamera("Camera", new BABYLON.Vector3(1, 1, 1), scene)
console.log(camera.getTarget())
```

And when i run it the console prints

```
{ _isDirty: true, _x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0 }
```

But the position is always 0 on every axis, no matter where i put the camera! What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: have you tried accessing the `camera.position` or `camera.globalPosition` properties?

Comment: those returned null for some reason

Comment: The 2nd parameter in the ctor specifies the camera position, not its target. Thus, there’s no target set when you call getTarget